# How to reduce distortion in a TPA3110D2 amplifier?

Tags: distortion

I bought these cheap amplifiers (2x15W TPA3110, the red ones with four caps and 4 inductors.) They sound good at normal volumes but then distort at high volumes.  When I increase the input voltage, it becomes a bit cleaner but still distorts at peak volume.  I am using 21V to power it, and I don't want to try anything more than that because the amplifier gets damaged easily.

Comment: You get exactly what you pay for usually.

Comment: *distort at high volumes* This is a 15 W into 8 ohms amplifier, it will distort if you if you try to exceed that. Consider that distortion can also be added by the speakers. Note that a speaker that is not build into a speaker box will not be able to handle its rated power. So before you say that this amplifier isn't good enough, you need to make sure that the rest of the system is good enough. Also consider that a 2 x 10 W quality amplifier combined with good quality sensitive speakers can provide a better sound quality than a 2 x 100 W amplifier with crappy and insensitive speakers.

Comment: Turn the volume down.